# PL/SQL function to return string with regexp special chars escaped

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

Is there an existing PL/SQL method which takes a string and returns the same string but with backslashes preceding any regexp chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result := REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, '([$^[()+*?{\|])', '\\\1', 1, 0, 'c');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong I think those REGEXP_ functions are 10g only? Amnyway for Ora9 I used:

owa_pattern.change(strResult,'[+,.,(,)[,*,\,^,$,|,?,{,#]','\\' || '&','g');

Comment: REGEXP functions are new in 10g.  Since the question is about regular expressions, I assumed you were working with 10g.  You didn't say.

Comment: Never assume ;)  Seriously tho, sorry about not mentioning the Oracle version.